# SVG <use xlink:href> from a CDN

Tags: svg, cdn, xlink, svg-sprite

I am using the `<use xlink:href>` to reference my `svg` file.
It works fine on my local but throws an error (CORS) when I reference it from a CDN.  It looks as though the `xlink:href` doesn't allow the **CORS** request but I am wondering if there is any solution?

On the other hand, I have heard that this sprite technique is deprecated on **SVG2**.  So what is the best solution to use sprite SVG file for now that works on all different browsers including mobile browsers.

Comment: @Chenmunka Please don't suggest edits to remove tags. This takes at least three people to review, whereas people with >2k rep can do these edits singlehandedly. We appreciate your willingness to cooperate, but this is unfortunately not the right way.

Answer (score 5):

The simplest cross-browser solution I've found is to fetch the SVG sprite via ajax and embed it in your page:

```html
<div id="svg-container" style="display: none"></div>
<script>
!function() {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", '/path/to/cdn/sprite.svg');
    xhr.onload = function() {
        document.getElementById('svg-container').innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
    }
    xhr.send();
}();
</script>
```

This also saves you from specifying the SVG sprite's URL in `xlink:href`

```html
<svg>
    <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#heart"></use>
</svg>
```

Comment: I am not sure that this will get cached, as this technique can also be valid by using `xlink:href="path/to/file#heart`. Thanks for your help! I can't believe that I asked this 3 years ago :)) I am not sure if this is still valid tho! Thanks a lot