# Sprite.svg file link from CDN in angular not working?

Tags: angular, svg, sprite, cdn

How to add sprite-svg link for angular?

I have a local sprite.svg file which I want to put on cdn but unfortunately link doesn't work.

When cdn link is referenced for sprite.svg#image-id in angular the image doesn't appear. All the other files from CDN works absolutely fine. I want to know whether it is possible or not? And if yes then how?

I want to use it for something like this

```
<svg>
     <use xlink:href="https://cdn.com/images/sprite.svg#image-id"></use>
</svg>
```

Comment: it is not only Angular related

Comment: please check out the related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39617188/svg-use-xlinkhref-from-a-cdn