# Github browser preview doesn't show slider nor bootstrap icons

Tags: node.js, github, owl-carousel

I am new to GITHUB and NODE.js and I've tryed to put a page online on GITHUB but the way I see it is different from the way it shows up on my LOCALHOST.

Basically in the GITHUB link I can't see the OWL Carousel I used nor the Bootstrap Icons. While in my LOCALHOST it works properly.

What am I missing here?

Web page: https://lfavilla.github.io/rastelli/
Repository: https://github.com/lfavilla/rastelli

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your resources are loading from `node_modules` which is not available on github, it shouldn't available on git.

you are trying to load resources like `https://lfavilla.github.io/rastelli/node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.slim.min.js`

[image]

Run `npm run build` on your project and update git with build folder

In your index.html file use CDN version of jquery

Change

```
<script src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
```

to

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.slim.js"></script>
```

Also, change your bootstrap icon references to CDN

```
https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.4.0/icons/chevron-down.svg
```

you can find icons CDN here https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.4.0/icons/

Comment: My project in github was already done like this. I rerun "npm run build" and there are no updates to be commited. Thanks for you time and support.

Comment: @LucianoFavilla Updated the answer, try hope it works for you.

Comment: I sse that my "starter.js" points to node_modules:
import "../../node_modules/bootstrap/js/dist/util.js";
import "../../node_modules/bootstrap/js/dist/modal.js";
import "../../node_modules/owl.carousel/dist/owl.carousel.js";
Should I change this?

Comment: @LucianoFavilla yes you should use CDN version bootstrap and carousel or you can extract them into the root folder and upload them to the github repo.

Comment: the Carouosel now works with CDN. Thanks a lot! But the Bootstrap icons don't. If I go to the SGV link I see it, but on my page they are not loaded.

Comment: @LucianoFavilla Cool, try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39617188

Comment: @LucianoFavilla you can download svg icons to local assets directory and use it.

Comment: Thanks once again @Tushar-Gupa. The problem now is that changing it to IMAGE I can't only use CSS to change icons sizes and colors.